# Why I can't use number() on input value?

Tags: javascript, html

why I can't use javascript number() on input value?

Got this HTML code

```
<input type="text" id="someId" value="1" min="0">
```

and I'm trying to handle it from javascript with:

```
var counter = document.getElementById("someID");
var currentCounter = counter.value;
counter.value = number(currentCounter)+1;
```

It's not working. It works only with parseInt:

```
var counter = document.getElementById("someID");
var currentCounter = counter.value;
counter.value = parseInt(currentCounter)+1;
```

Anybody know why? Thank you.

Comment: Because it's `Number` and not `number` which the browser should have told you in the console.

Comment: Pro-tip: [Open your console.](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/hello-world/714/using-console-log) It will tell you when you make mistakes like this.

Comment: Thanks. I'm pretty new to this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is `Number`, not `number`

```
var counter = document.getElementById("someID");
var currentCounter = counter.value;
counter.value = Number(currentCounter) + 1;
//-------------^^^^^^^
```